# Problem when processing more than 20 records

Tags: mysql, go

I am using the `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` library to interact with my MySQL database. All works fine except when I have a query greater than 20 records. The query returns the result set fine but when loop through it panics when I get to the 21st record.

I query my db in this manner:

```
row, err = store.db.Query(myquerystring)
```

I am extracting the returned values like this:

```
indx = 0
for row.Next() {
    err = row.Scan(
       &mySlice[indx].Val1, &mySlice[indx].Val2
    )

    if err != nil {
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            log.Print("No records found")
        } else {
            log.Printf("Error retrieving data: %s", err.Error())
        }
    } 
    indx++
}
```

The error that I get is not from my error handling, it happens immediately upon retrieving the 21st record. I put logging in at as the first and last things within the for loop and I get the log for the end of the 20th record gets written but not the first log for the 21st record so it seems the `for row.Next()` line which causes the panic.

The error I get is:

```
http: panic serving xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

This is how I initialize my slice:

**sqlstring is the same query as above except all fields are removed from the select and only a `count(tableid)` is returned.

```
row, err := store.db.Query(sqlString)

row.Next()
err = row.Scan(
    &count,
)

var mySlice = make([]mystruct, count)
```

Stack Trace:

```
web_1  | 2019/11/21 03:03:23 4) record number: 19
web_1  | 2019/11/21 03:03:23 http: panic serving xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
web_1  | goroutine 811 [running]:
web_1  | net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc42047eaa0)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1721 +0xd0
web_1  | panic(0x7f8bc0, 0xa5c3a0)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf
web_1  | database/sql.(*Rows).Next(0x0, 0x87afa9)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2133 +0x30
web_1  | main.(*dbStore).GetVehicleCount(0xc420076230, 0x8865a0)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/store.go:1385 +0xa7
web_1  | main.(*dbStore).GetVehicles(0xc420076230, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/store.go:1415 +0xed
web_1  | main.(*dbStore).SearchTrips(0xc420076230, 0xed5540400, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/store.go:1220 +0x123
web_1  | main.CalendarReportHandler(0xa373e0, 0xc4200e3420, 0xc4200ce500)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/handlers.go:1559 +0x475
web_1  | net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x886ca0, 0xa373e0, 0xc4200e3420, 0xc4200ce500)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1942 +0x44
web_1  | app/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc4200d4180, 0xa373e0, 0xc4200e3420, 0xc4200ce500)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:212 +0xdf
web_1  | net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc42009bd90, 0xa373e0, 0xc4200e3420, 0xc4200ce300)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2568 +0x92
web_1  | net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc42047eaa0, 0xa37ae0, 0xc4203a9600)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0x612
web_1  | created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2668 +0x2ce
web_1  | 2019/11/21 03:03:23 Error retrieving drivers: Error 1040: Too many connections
web_1  | 2019/11/21 03:03:23 http: panic serving 172.26.0.1:58770: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
web_1  | goroutine 955 [running]:
web_1  | net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc4204e9040)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1721 +0xd0
web_1  | panic(0x7f8bc0, 0xa5c3a0)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf
web_1  | database/sql.(*Rows).Next(0x0, 0x87afa9)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:2133 +0x30
web_1  | main.(*dbStore).GetVehicleCount(0xc420076230, 0x0)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/store.go:1385 +0xa7
web_1  | main.(*dbStore).SearchTrips(0xc420076230, 0xed54d6c80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/store.go:1219 +0xf3
web_1  | main.CalendarReportHandler(0xa373e0, 0xc4200e3960, 0xc4200ce700)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/handlers.go:1559 +0x475
web_1  | net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x886ca0, 0xa373e0, 0xc4200e3960, 0xc4200ce700)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1942 +0x44
web_1  | app/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc4200d4180, 0xa373e0, 0xc4200e3960, 0xc4200ce700)
web_1  |        /go/src/app/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:212 +0xdf
web_1  | net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc42009bd90, 0xa373e0, 0xc4200e3960, 0xc420144000)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2568 +0x92
web_1  | net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc4204e9040, 0xa37ae0, 0xc4204e1940)
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0x612
web_1  | created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
web_1  |        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2668 +0x2ce
```

Comment: It looks like your slice `mySlice`  has 20 elements, and 21st one is causing panic.

Comment: It does appear to be an issue with the slice which is size 20. But I get the size from the number of records returned. I do a query before returning the count then use that to initialize the slice. I also pasted the query into mysql workbench and it returned 20 records as expected. It seems for some reason after the 20th record my loops is entered again when it should be done, I use this same query with dates (that is the only criteria in the where clause) and it works fine but this particular day that returns 20 records for some reasons iterates an extra time...not sure why???

Comment: added my slice initialization as requested.

Comment: Do you have the full panic message, with the stack?

Comment: If this is your actual code then: 1. do *not* ignore errors! 2. in those cases where you do check errors, if the error is non-nil, do *not* continue as if nothing happened, in most cases you should exit immediately. 3. `Query` returns a pointer to `sql.Rows`, not "row", this distinction is important because there is the `sql.Row` type in the `database/sql` package and it is different from the `sql.Rows` type. 4. An instance of the `sql.Rows` type *must* be closed, by the caller, when work with it is done.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am away from my office until tomorrow and will post a full stack then. Also thanks for the tips on improving my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you for the stack traces requests, it made me analyze the stack trace with a fine tooth comb leading me to the solution.

There were 2 problems.

My function to populate my slice had 2 other functions which got called to populate structs within my parent struct, due to the amount of records in the parent struct returning I exceeded the maximum number of connections available before the parent struct was populated. Explicitly closing the row object in these functions resolved this error.

The second was that I had a for loop where I was loop from 1 to the record count because I wanted to store value of 1 to "X" instead of 0 to "X-1" but this obviously resulted in an index out of range error (rookie mistake). This was easily resolved by simply looping normally and storing "X+1" in the variable.

Thanks for all the comments they helped me to find my own problems, much appreciated.